# How can i send a very long string to php in c#?

Tags: php, mysql

normally i can send a string to php with $_POST or $_GET, but my string is very long (like 10000 values)

and if i try to send it to my server i get this error: 414 very long url (or something like that) so, can you please tell me what are my options?

What i want to do is to receive that string so i can INSERT them into a table in a database (mysqli) ( my string looks like this: "1,4,0,5,6,9,...."

here is the php script I'm thinking of using:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost",$username, $password, $dbname);

$str = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['arraytile']);
$numerDeTiles = $_POST['ntiles']; //verylongstting
$contador = $_POST['contador']; //number of database
$array = explode(",", $numerDeTiles );


$query = "insert into grid".$contador." values (NULL,(?));";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt ->bind_param("s" , $one);
$conn->query("START TRANSACTION");
foreach ($array as $one){
$stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->query("COMMIT");
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I think this is ok (not being tested) but my problem is how i will receive this very large string

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'm sorry, i made a mistake in the comments of the code! the very long string is the 'array tile'  not ntiles

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Also, don't comment with corrections; edit them into the question instead.

Comment: `POST` is the right method to send large data.

Comment: the problem is that i can't do it with POST because the error 414 very long url, i think the max length to send a string this way is 2000.

Comment: its not POST, if its in the URI

Comment: I'm confused, as you can see, my script says POST not GET

Comment: yes, but that's the receiving script, the issue is with the sender

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are getting the 414 means your uri is too long. That makes me suspect you are making a GET request in stead of using POST. POST variables should not be in the uri, but in the body of the request. Apache / php may enforce some size limits on the request body size, but 10k should be fine (check your .ini or run phpinfo() if you want to be sure).

So in short, make sure you use POST!